# Size of fading edge in Android's Scroll View

Tags: android, android-xml, android-scrollview

I'm trying to add a fading edge in a Scroll View by adding the following property to the XML:

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
```

Now what I want is to manage the size of this fading edge, I've tried using :

> android:fadingEdgeLength="10dp"

but it doesn't have any effect on the final result.

Any guess of what to do it?

Answer (score 3):

set padding to scrollview..thats trick

```
android:paddingTop="10dp" 
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:fadingEdgeLength="10dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fading Edge length must be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred font size), in (inches), mm (millimeters).

Answer (score 0):

That's the right property to use, anyway the fading edge might not be looking as you expect.

If that's the scenario the you may be able to achieve the precise look and feel by overlapping a view with a fading gradient shape in its background property.